# Handling SIGINT in parallel fabric task

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, fabric

I'm using a `multiprocessing.Manager` to keep track of resources that I create in a parallel fabric task. If something goes wrong I often want to do a `ctrl-c` to halt the tasks, however I still need those resources printed.

How can I make `report_resources` *always* run before exit and work correctly in the following code:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Manager
from fabric.utils import puts
from fabric.context_managers import hide,settings
from fabric.api import env,task,execute
from fabric.colors import green
import atexit
import signal

env.resources_log = Manager().list() 
def report_resources(x=None,y=None):
    if env.resources_log:
        puts(green( 'we really really want to print these, no matter what happens' ))
        for r in env.resources_log:
            puts(green('\t * '+str(r) ))

atexit.register(report_resources)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, report_resources) # This doesn't work at catching ctrl-c in multiprocessing code

@task
def test():
    def par_task():
        env.resources_log.append("some resource")
        puts( 'appended resource' )
        # HIT CTRL-C HERE
        sleep(10)

    puts('starting multithreading')
    with settings( hide("running","stdout")
                 , hosts=['foo','bar']
                 , parallel=True):
        execute(par_task)
```

If I let it run I get:

```
starting multithreading
[foo] appended resource
[bar] appended resource

Done.
we really really want to print these, no matter what happens
     * some resource
     * some resource
```

However if I ctrl-c during the sleep I get:

```
starting multithreading
[bar] appended resource
[foo] appended resource
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/foo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 739, in main
[foo] we really really want to print these, no matter what happens
    *args, **kwargs
...
... lots of garbage
```

I've tried various `try` / `catch` arrangements, hiding the signals with [this method](http://noswap.com/blog/python-multiprocessing-keyboardinterrupt) but nothing seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling signal.signal with SIGTERM, not SIGINT. Doesn't CTRL-C usually result in a SIGINT, not SIGTERM? [1]

I would try using SIGINT instead of SIGTERM with signal.signal().

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C

Comment: Oops, you're right. I think I was using SIGINT but copied it over into my test code wrong. I've updated the question and some sample output with `SIGINT`.